# Spark Dataframe Pivot on Word in String

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Basically I have a dataframe column (String type) that contains english sentences.  My goal is to create a pivot table (grouped by user ids) that has words as columns and counts as entries.  The problem is that if you do something like

```
myDataframe.groupBy(col("user")).pivot(col("sentences")).count()
```

Where "sentences" is the name of the column containing the english sentences, you will be counting the sentences rather than the individual words.  Is there any way to count the individual words in the sentences and not just the sentences themselves? Whitespace tokenization is fine.

Comment: I just discovered this `explode()` function.  Maybe I can use a udf to tokenize the column and create a new array column with the tokenization.  Then explode the new column to create another column, then groupBy user and pivot on the exploded column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tokenize and explode first:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer

new Tokenizer()
 .setInputCol("sentences")
 .setOutputCol("tokens")
 .transform(df)
 .withColumn("token", explode($"tokens"))
 .groupBy(col("user")).pivot(col("token")).count()
```

Comment: This is what I thought too :)  I'll try it now then accept